# Read N lines until EOF in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi tried several solutions found on SO but I am missing some info.

I want to read 4 lines at once until I hit EOF. I know how to do it in other languages, but what is the best approach in Python 3?

This is what I have, `lines` is always the first 4 lines and the code stops afterwards (I know, because the comprehension only gives me the first 4 elements of `all_lines`. I could use some kind of counter and break and so on, but that seems rather cheap to me.

```
if os.path.isfile(myfile):
    with open(myfile, 'r') as fo:
        all_lines = fo.readlines()
        for lines in all_lines[:4]:
            print(lines)
```

I want to handle 4 lines at once until I hit EOF. The file I am working with is rather short, maybe about 100 lines MAX

Comment: Hey @doublevoid, just to be clear: you want a subfunction that takes in lines of chunk size = 4, until you reach the end of file correct? Suppose the file was 7 lines long -- would you want one chunk of 4, and one chunk of 3?

Comment: Correct, if the file has 7 lines, it's okay if the last chunk contains only 3 lines. :)

Comment: Got it. In that case I think @Francsco Court answered it!

Comment: Thanks, I am checking his answer out right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate the lines in chunks of 4, you can do something like this:

```
if os.path.isfile(myfile):
    with open(myfile, 'r') as fo:
        all_lines = fo.readlines()
        for i in range(0, len(all_lines), 4):
            print(all_lines[i:i+4])
```

Comment: This works just fine :) Is there a way to tell Python to always generate 4 entries, even when there are less than 4 values left? I am using `lines = all_lines[i:i+4]` => `lines[3]` could cause an exception when there are only 7 lines in the file. Checking for None than len() seems more elegant to me here. Anyway marked as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading in the whole file and then looping over the lines four at a time, you can simply read them in four at a time. Consider

```
def fun(myfile):
    if not os.path.isfile(myfile):
        return
    with open(myfile, 'r') as fo:
        while True:
            for line in (fo.readline() for _ in range(4)):
                if not line:
                    return
                print(line)
```

Here, a generator expression is used to read four lines, which is embedded in an "infinite" loop, which stop when `line` is falsy (the empty `str` `''`), which only happens when we have reached EOF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I want to process 4 lines at one, in one block, this does not work. the loop is giving me each line at once, except I missed something here?!